# Stretched background image in subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Aroundabouts the internet, I've come across the following code for stretching an image to fill a UIView:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

This is all well and good. But I thought I'd repurpose the code to work for a custom UIView class being used as a subview, and put the following code in `initWithCoder:` (since the views are being added in storyboard) as follows:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] drawInRect:self.bounds];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note that I've changed "self.view" to simply "self" to reflect that this code is being called by the view itself and not by a view controller. The first code sample works great, and fills the view grandly. The second doesn't (even if I put it in the view controller ala `self.subView.frame.size`), and I have a feeling it's because I don't properly understand *frame* and *bounds*. Can somebody give me a quick crash course, or (if I'm way off base) point out what's actually wrong?

EDIT: Now I'm really confused. Using NSLog, I've gleaned the following information:

```
self.view.bounds.size.width: 768
self.subView.bounds.size.width: 0
```

...Huh?? The same is true of frame. But... it's on there, it's got dimensions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be an easier way to accomplish what you are wanting to do. If I understand you correctly, you're looking to have `image.png` be a background image for your custom view. If so, all you'll need to do is add a `UIImageView` when you initialize your custom view.

```
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: coder];
    if (self) {

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: self.bounds];
        [imageView setAutoresizingMask: (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
        [imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"]];
        [self addSubview: imageView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I had tried something similar to this before but I missed the apparently crucial `setAutoresizingMask` bit and it didn't work. Thanks muchly!